# What does a server resource quota of 0 mean?

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration

In SharePoint Online it is possible to configure a value for server resources. In our environment we have 1300 "units" of this available. We have 1 public site and 1 private site.

Does a server resource of 0 mean that:

1. The server has no dedicated resources and will take a lower priority to those which do have resources allocated
2. The server has no dedicated resources and will take a higher priority to those which do have resources allocated
3. The server has no use of resources

The documentation states that

> "The purpose of this quota is to set a maximum percentage of server
>   resources (such as CPU and RAM) that your site collection should use"

For example, if I allocate 800 to my public site and 0 to my private site, will my private site use 0, 500, or 1300 take away whatever the public site is currently using?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**
Found some more information regarding resource usage quota on Site Collections [here](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/p/165480/474843.aspx#474843)

> Resource quota is determined by the number of user seats in the
>   company's license. To calculate resource quota in Office 365, you can
>   use the following equation: (#seats×200) +300.  For example, in a
>   typical 25 seat license, the available resource quota would be 5300.

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question, but is there any custom/sandbox code in a plain installation? We've only just enabled our site and were having issues with the admin sections of the public site not responding until we changed the value of resource quota from the default of 0 to a non-zero number. Is this just coincidence?

Comment: No I think now I realized you where actually talking about the Site Collection resource usage quota. Added information regarding how that is calculated.

Comment: @Robert, do you have a link that describes the (#seats*200)+300 calculation?  I can see the storage base calculation at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/sharepoint-online-software-boundaries-and-limits-HA102694293.aspx, but not a resource quota calculation for the tenant.

Comment: @KirkLiemohn, not anymore it seems, it was posted on the link above before but seems to have been edited away. Not sure why...

Comment: @Robert, thanks for trying.  FWIW, if I had 3 more licensed users the math would work out for me.  I may have added wrong (had to add up all the used resource quota values from each site collection, so maybe I made a mistake).  I'll create a support request and see if it gets answered that way.  I'll report back here if I learn anything else.